# React - Render an Action To show the details of that specific Work

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Difficult question...please understand.

I'm trying to render an action when I click a button to show the details of that specific work that I have on an array. The problem is that because the button is inside the the Map function, it repeats on all my work, and I want a specific detail for each. Sorry if I'm not explaining very well.

This is my work list container:

```
class ListaTrabalhos extends Component {

renderList(){
    return this.props.trabalhos.map((trabalho) => {
        return (
            <li>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img key={trabalho.title} src={trabalho.img} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                        <h3>{trabalho.title}</h3>
                        <p>{trabalho.descricao}</p>
                        <button key={trabalho.title} onClick={() => this.props.selectTrabalho(trabalho)} type="button" className="btn btn-info">Detalhes</button>
                    </div>
                    <TrabalhoDetail />
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    })
}

render() {

return (

    <ul className="list-group col-ms-4">
        {this.renderList()}
    </ul>

   );

  }
}
```

This is my work list detail container:

```
class TrabalhoDetail extends Component {
render() {
    if (!this.props.trabalho) {
        return <div>Teste</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Detalhes:</h3>
            <div>{this.props.trabalho.title}</div>
            <div>{this.props.trabalho.tec}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
return {
    trabalho: state.activeTrabalho
};
}
```

I hope to be specific, if you need more info please tell-me, I'm new to this, and I'm trying to understand, already have made a lot of changes and its not working...

Again, the objective is to show the work details on a specific work that I click and not in all of them. The key is working so when I click a specific detail it shows the correct one, but keeps showing the others and I only want to see the one I click.

Thanks in advance, sorry if it's confusing.

```
export function selectTrabalho(trabalho) {

// selectBook é um ActionCreator, precisa de returnar uma ação
// Um objecto com uma propriedade Type

return {
    type: 'WORK_SELECTED',
    payload: trabalho
};

}
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `this.props.selectTrabalho`.

Comment: The definition ? the translate ? this.props.selectWork, sorry. i made it in Portuguese. Is that what you mean ? im not understanding...sorry. ITs my index.js in actions folder, i have poste it !

Comment: This may be helpful: there is a [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com). (Which would be "Estouro de pilha" :))

Comment: I'm guessing all you need to do is move `<TrabalhoDetail />` outside the `map`. So `<ul className="list-group col-ms-4">
        {this.renderList()} <TrabalhoDetail />
    </ul>`

Comment: No :( !! its not working , i already have tried that, if i do that the details will be in the end of the page and not in one of each work.Thanks for the help